# What voltage should power requirements be listed as?

Tags: power, mains

I am listing the power requirements for a culmination of multiple devices for the US and the EU.

For 120 volt mains, it appears most list the requirements (amperage) relative to 115 volt. Should I do this as well?

How about for 230 volt mains?

Comment: Depends. Do you have wide range as in 100-240 (88 - 264 in reality) VAC or dual range like 100-120, 220-240 VAC?

Comment: Many devices are universal input these days, 90-264VAC for example.  I that case it makes sense to rate the power consumption of the device in watts, as that will be relatvely constant (except for changes in efficiency with voltage.)

Comment: Also see my previous comment for a similar question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244685/input-power-rating-on-power-supplies-how-does-max-amp-draw-apply-to-220v

Comment: @winny Some of the components are dual range, some are wide range. I believe ideally we'd list 120V and 230V separately.

Comment: If you list 230 VAC in Europe, that's +-10% whereas if you list 220-240 VAC, that's +-6%. I can't say 230 VAC is discouraged, but it's uncommon. Usually you go for 50-60 Hz, 100-240 VAC listed and tested for 47-63 Hz and 88-264 VAC by an UL body with CB credentials or CB body with cUL credentials and be done with all of it.

Answer (score 1):

> For 120 volt mains, it appears most list the requirements (amperage)
>   relative to 115 volt. Should I do this as well? How about for 230 volt
>   mains?

For CE (European) marking you have to specify the maximum rated current and, for universal input AC appliances, the maximum current will almost certainly be taken at the lowest AC voltage (maybe 85V). I am assuming of course that your device uses a SMPS to deliver low voltage DC to the functional electronic parts.

Think of the person buying it - they have to have some idea what the maximum current it could take. There's nothing wrong in specifying a whole range of stuff if you want to but don't foul up what the legislation asks you to put.

As per Winny's comment on the other post, go a bit higher to ensure every product can comply.

Comment: And put the consumption in watts on it so that smarter consumers can figure out the actual running cost.

Comment: It's actually the culmination of multiple different SMPSs and then what I presume are AC motors inside of fans. Your explanation helps me understand their power requirements, but because they all list different ranges, I believe I need to normalize my culmination to a specific voltage, which is what the single plug the owner will use requires.