# Mismatch between Input Power and Output Power in a typical Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

[image]

Here are the data attached on a Switching Mode Power Supply :
Input : 230 V - 2.5 A PF = 0.95 ( Hence the power can be obtained as 230*2.5*0.95 = 546 W )

Output : 300 + 103 + 3.6 + 12.5 = 419.1
And at the line bellow the table it has mentioned 330 Watt as the Total wattage.
How can this be possible ?

Comment: Were you expecting 100% efficient power conversion?

Comment: That is a bit confusing as is though.. If you do the math for each voltage column you get 544.4w.. and what is total wattage.... You may need to look at the manual to figure out what combined and total really mean.

Comment: I would expect 80-90% and that still does not explain it.

Comment: See also previous discussion here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244685/input-power-rating-on-power-supplies-how-does-max-amp-draw-apply-to-220v

Comment: I had a [simmilair question](https://superuser.com/q/1805179/1237653) on the superuser community.

Answer (score 4):

Even if 95% efficient , current rating is **always for breaker load rating** considering surge currents with even soft start on input.  and does not imply efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

As is generally true for multiple output power supplies, some outputs can supply higher power if other outputs are more lightly loaded. The key to understanding is that total overall power dissipation in the supply (due to it not being 100% efficient) has to be limited due to net temperature rise, cooling and component stresses. In this case the supply appears to be designed to deliver a continuous 330W output power apportioned among its outputs.