# Why is there a seemingly big difference in power supply input and output watts?

Tags: power-supply

Looking at a power supply like [Corsair AX 860W power supply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pMIl.png) I notice there seems to be a big difference between the AC input watts (240 V x 5.5 A = **1320 W**) and DC output watts (**860 W**).

I read on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1164933/1237653) that virtually all power supplies are now 80-90% efficient, but the way I calculated, this power supply is only about 65.15% efficient (860 / 1320 = 0.65151).

I noticed a similar but worse thing with my Lenovo IdeaPad3 laptop power supply:

| Power | Volts | Amps | Watts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC input | 240 V | 1.7 A | 408 W |
| DC output | 20 V | 3.25 A | 65 W |
|  |  | Effeciency | **16%** |

Comment: what makes you think the peak current is the continuous current draw?

Comment: This question has been asked (and answered) many, many times on the site. Check the "Related" list on the right and you should find some. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/298862/mismatch-between-input-power-and-output-power-in-a-typical-power-supply?rq=1 is one but I haven't checked if it directly answers your question.

Comment: I seriously doubt that your laptop supply is wasting 343 watts as heat, it would be a little more than warm to the touch.

Answer (score 4):

DC output Watts is continuous real power, AC input *current* relates to maximum *apparent* power (namely disregarding the power factor that can end up somewhat significant for a power supply serving both 50Hz/60Hz and 100V–240V).

The output spec is what is guaranteed to be a deliverable on a continuing base, the input spec is what fuses should be rated for to account both for reactive power components and for momentary load spikes (and inrush currents) exceeding the continuous power rating.

Answer (score 2):

The 5.5 A rating is the maximum current that it might draw at a given moment, such as at startup. It is not the actual draw at any given moment, which depends on what the load draws and on the power factor. The input AC current may be out of phase with the AC voltage. That portion of the current does no work; it is returned to the grid. Read up about [Power factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor).

You are calculating efficiency as:

```
E = (max instantaneous AC current * nominal AC voltage) / Maximum output power.
```

Instead the efficiency listed in the papers you read is:

```
E = Actual input power / Actual output power @ ~ 80 % of nominal power.
```