# Understanding relation between energy use, watts and amps

Tags: amperage, energy, watts, cost

I'm looking into air conditioners and I've been unable to fully understand the relation between watts, amps and the energy ratings (in this case, the one used in the United States, the yellow Energy Guide label).

Both are 115 V.

Air conditioner 1: 8000 BTU, it is listed as 660 W cooling power, 6.2 A cooling current. The yellow label Energy Guide lists yearly costs at $65. The energy efficiency ratio is 12.

Air conditioner 2: 9500 BTU, it is listed as 920 W cooling power, 11.5 A cooling current. The yellow label Energy Guide lists yearly costs at $50. The energy efficiency ratio is 13.8.

Questions:

- Why in both air conditioners the amps is not equal to watts divided by 115 volts? 660 / 115 = 5.74 A and 920 / 115 = 8 A.
- The air conditioner 1 clearly uses less energy than air conditioner 2. However air conditioner 2 is listed as cheaper in yearly costs. Maybe it has to do with the way it cools the room, using less energy over time? But then why watts are higher, if the energy consumption is lower?

Thanks for helping me understanding this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input power rating on power supplies - how does max amp draw apply to 220V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244685/input-power-rating-on-power-supplies-how-does-max-amp-draw-apply-to-220v)

Comment: in short: it's average vs peak.

Comment: What are the efficiency ratings? Usually given in SEER.

Comment: 8000 BTU/hr is 2344w, so 660W is probably the power consumption and not the cooling power.  In this case the nominal coefficient of performance would be 2344/660 = 3.5, which is reason for a cheaper AC unit.

Comment: @LShaver air conditioner 1 is 12.0 and air conditioner 2 is 13.8. I don't know what they mean.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks, but I still don't understand why they might be mixing average/peak watts and amps. Shouldn't watts and amps be related even if they list peak consumption? Sorry if I sounded confused, just a customer trying to understand better.

Comment: they don't list short-term peak power consumption (i.e. with a 1/(60 Hz) resolution), they list maximum medium-term power consumption, like, averaged over minutes. Current, however, needs to be limited per cycle!

Comment: @MarcusMüller So you are saying air conditioner 2 can peak 11.5 A but its medium-term power consumption is 920 watts?

Comment: @igorjrr The manufacturers have no interest in helping you compare apples to apples. And at least in the US, I wouldn't trust any of the figures without investigating them, in detail. There is almost no oversight in the US, outside of torts. So you are on your own here. "Cooling power" is a US-centric term (which already should tell you to "watch out.") But it is based on some hypothetical block of ice melting for a fixed period -- like a day. In short, it doesn't relate directly to actual power consumption of the device. It's something the manufacturer wants you to use for comparison. +1

Comment: @jonk Understood. But aren't they required to specify the actual power consumption (in watts and or amps)? Usually this is listed in the power supply or unit, but I don't have it yet and I'm trying to find what is the power consumption.

Comment: @igorjrr Sure. They have to tell you the approximate truth with respect to actual voltage and current because you have a legal right to know for safety reasons. You need to be able to know that the unit will work on a specified circuit in your home. So they will tell you the worst-case current requirements and it will be rated to operate on the usual residential split-phase power system. I've always been able to find this, on new machines, on a label usually at the back or bottom. If you ask, they should give it to you, as well.

Comment: @igorjrr But if you don't know how the Energy Guide calculates its numbers (and I don't), then I wouldn't really use them. You don't know what you don't know. And until you know what you don't know, you won't know what further questions to ask. If you haven't already figured it out, the US is a complete anarchy system for manufacturers. They can do pretty much what they want. No meaningful oversight. And they control the gov't organs which we are supposed to trust. So just don't  trust anything until you do your own independent work (due diligence.)

Answer (score 1):

> Why in both air conditioners the amps is not equal to watts divided by 115 volts? 660 / 115 = 5.74 A and 920 / 115 = 8 A.

Simply because you AC units have a power factor less than unity. The "W/V = A" is only true for DC circuits and AC circuits provided the load looks resistive to the source (i.e. it has a power factor equal to 1). The compressor in these units are typically inductive in nature; newer units are powered be variable-frequency invertors with active power factor correction so they are (almost) resistive loads and the "W/V=A" formula will approximate this case well.

> The air conditioner 1 clearly uses less energy than air conditioner 2. However air conditioner 2 is listed as cheaper in yearly costs. Maybe it has to do with the way it cools the room, using less energy over time? But then why watts are higher, if the energy consumption is lower?

The "energy savings" language is purely marketing. Only until you include the full context (climate, hours used per day, cost of kWh, set temperature, room insulation, ect.) can you make a proper comparison.

The objective measures are: watts, seer rating and BTU's/h. The way you want to size your unit is based on the BTU's/h that will be required. Figuring out how many BTU's/h is beyond the scope of this questing but there are calculators for this. You need, at minimum, the room size, number of windows, and you climate zone. Next, you want the unit that draws the least power for the BTU/h requirement. Also, you don't want to oversize the unit thinking that's going to work better, what happens is a big ass unit will cool the room very quickly, but won't remove much humidity. So than your stuck sitting in a cold, clammy room that's not comfortable.

Obviously other factors will play a roll in your selection besides efficiency. The brand matters too. Some units are more reliable than others. What good is little more efficiency if your system breaks down every other month?

Comment: While the "energy saving" label is marketspeek, A/C units pretty much do have different efficiencies and for particular case the difference can be as much as twice (or more, if we talk about heating). I am not familiar with US efficiency marks, but EU ones have honest measurements to back them.

Answer (score 0):

The Energy Guide numbers include a range of assumptions about room size, annual hours of operation, and cooling load. The manufacturers have to include values for standby power consumption as well. All of this means that while watts, amps, and volts are fundamentally related, the values reported on the label aren't. They are the result of specific testing requirements and reporting criteria that manufacturers must adhere to.

**What you can assume is that in a similar application (such as the same room in your house) air conditioner (2) will cost you about 30% less to operate annually than air conditioner (1):**

`($65 - $50) / $50 = 30%`

---

If you want to get into the details, you can read the [Code of Federal Regulations -- Title 10 Energy -- Chapter II Department of Energy -- Subchapter D Energy Conservation -- Part 430 Energy Conservation Program for Consumer Products -- Subpart B Test Procedures -- Section 23 Test procedures for the measurement of energy and water consumption](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=5f7660bb12d69ad97eb22daec42edcdf&mc=true&node=pt10.3.430&rgn=div5#se10.3.430_123).

Here you'll find that assumed annual operation is 750 hours. More specifics are found in [Appendix F to Subpart B of Part 430—Uniform Test Method for Measuring the Energy Consumption of Room Air Conditioners](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=5f7660bb12d69ad97eb22daec42edcdf&mc=true&node=pt10.3.430&rgn=div5#ap10.3.430_127.f), which references  [ANSI/AHAM RAC-1-2015
Room Air Conditioners](https://webstore.ansi.org/standards/aham/ansiahamrac2015), the testing standard that manufacturers need to follow when developing the numbers that go on the label.